# What are the benefits of super type sub type table

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, denormalization, supertype

Suppose any one designing the Database(ER model) and he have three tables CHECKING-ACCOUNT, SAVINGS-ACCOUNT, and LOAN-ACCOUNT.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKmZP.png).

Suppose he is aware of super type -sub type relationship. So he implemented the super type - sub type.

[new structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iocQH.png)

My question is - After implementing super type - sub type relationship what benefit or advantages he get? is implementing super type - sub type a best practice?

Comment: I'm just not sure why he wouldn't just have account table with account type, accountid, accountbalance all in the same table.

Comment: if we always use one table, to store similar(not 100% similar) type of things (few column same and few different) then what is the use of super type - sub type relationship?

Comment: If there are lots of columns in each table that have nothing to do with each other, you might not want the bloat of many null columns. Or if you have many subtypes, you would again end up with many null columns. sub-super prevents those issues.

Comment: This is a faq, google stackoverflow database sql table subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism and/or multiple/many relationships/associations/FKs. PS Please use text when you can, like here DDL & code blocks instead of images for your ERD & table (respectively).

Comment: You might want to look into a couple of tags.  [Tag:class-table-inheritance] and [Tag:single-table-inheritance]

Answer (score 3):

The advantages are that supertypes allow us to unify common attributes, relationships and integrity for multiple entity sets, while subtypes allow us to support type-specific attributes, relationships and integrity constraints. This allows us to simplify the database and our queries and enforce tighter integrity.

In your first example, we would need to query each of the 3 tables separately if we wanted to know when all accounts were opened or reviewed. If we wanted to establish a relationship between accounts and customers, we would need 3 separate relationships, and 3 separate queries to get all customers and accounts. Constraints like ensuring review dates occurred after opening dates would have to be defined 3 times.

Without subtypes, we would need to support all possible attributes and relationships for a single common type, and our queries would have to include type-specific logic to handle different rows separately. We could not easily enforce type-specific constraints, like positive interest rates which don't apply to checking accounts.